# How does Apache Ignite deploy in K8S?

Tags: ignite

On the Ignite website, I see that in Amazon EKS, Microsoft Azure Kubernetes Service Deployment, and Google Kubernetes Engine Deployment, deploy on each of the three platforms ignite.If I am on my own deployed K8S, can I deploy?Is it the same as deploying the Ignite on three platforms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, just skip the initial EKS/Azure initialization steps since you don't need them and move directly to the K8s configuration.

Alternatively, you might try [Apache Ignite and GridGain k8s operator](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/installation-guide/operator/overview) that simplifies the deployment.

Comment: I found the following instructions:
The operator is in beta state and under active development. We do not recommend using it on your production enviroment without additional testing

Comment: I found that Apache Ignite and GridGain K8s Operator is provided by GridGain, can fit Apache Ignite 2.9?

Comment: Sure, it is designed to work with both editions

Comment: I found the following instructions: The operator is in beta state and under active development. We do not recommend using it on your production enviroment without additional testing. I want to use Apache Ignite in a production environment, but GridGain K8s Operator is not recommended

Comment: I think it's fine to give it a try. Just remember to test it carefully before applying it in production. And keep in mind that version compatibility is not guaranteed since it's a beta release.